# ggplot2 override fixed aesthetic with mapped aes

Tags: r, ggplot2

When programming a `stat_summary` function, is there a way to override pre-programmed aesthetics:

```
library(ggplot2)

## Make base plot
p <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point()  

## Define function for stat summary
stat_sum_df <- function(fun = median, geom="point", colour = "red", ...) {
  stat_summary(fun.y = fun, colour = colour, geom = geom, size = 4, ...)
}

## Add summary stat to plot
p + stat_sum_df()
```

[image]

```
## Try to override colour with aes mapping: doesn't work
p + stat_sum_df(mapping = aes(colour = Species))
# same as above
```

[image]

This is away around it but I'm not sure if it is the most robust way:

```
## Hack?
stat_sum_hack <- function(fun = median, geom = "point", colour = "red", ...) {
  params <- list(...)

  if ("mapping" %in% names(params)) {
    stat_summary(fun.y = fun, geom = geom, size = 4, ...)
  } else {
    stat_summary(fun.y = fun, colour = colour, geom = geom, size = 4, ...)
  }
}

p + stat_sum_hack(mapping = aes(colour = Species))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why do you want to hardcode a color in the function? Like to provide a default? I'm pretty sure aesthetics set outside the `aes` take precedence over ones set inside

Comment: Yes exactly I want to provide default colours but optionally override by mapping an aes.

Comment: I think your approach is nice

Comment: I see. I don't think what you've done is particularly hacky. If you take your function a step further and define your own `Stat` object, you can use [`update_stat_defaults`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/update_defaults.html)

Comment: Better yet, I'm looking at the `ggplot2` source to see how defaults are set and how mappings are passed into stats, such as how the default ribbon fill is set for [`geom_smooth`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-smooth.r). But that might become a bigger undertaking than you want. For a `ggproto`, this is done in the argument `default_aes`.